# Mediawiki: создание категорий и стили на сайте

Tags: cms, css

Установил mediawiki, но ничего не отображается на сайте и не понятно как создать категории.

[image]

Comment: Да собственно решалось все тут, на серваке отрубили мбстринг.

Comment: @ruby, я почти угадал в ныне удаленном вандалами комментарии :-) Для кошерности сделайте решение ответом.

Comment: Давайте вы напишите ответ, а я плюсану)

Comment: @ruby, неа, цензоры загубили дискуссию об уместности вопроса в кодерском разделе, а не в админском, поэтому не могу, простите. И если честно очков моя догадка общего характера не заслуживает. Кнопка "Ответить на свой вопрос" у Вас не работает?

Comment: Нужно иметь 50 очков, чтобы ответить на свой вопрос, у меня к сожалению меньше.

Comment: @ruby, поправил :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение: включить на сервере мбстринг